# Parsing comments, finding links and embedded video

Tags: php, regex

Right now I have a variable: $blogbody which contains the entire contents of a blog.

I'm using the following to convert URLS to clickable links:

```
$blogbody = ereg_replace("[[:alpha:]]+://[^<>[:space:]]+[[:alnum:]/]","<a href=\"\\0\">\\0</a>", $blogbody);
```

And the following to resize embedded video:

```
$blogbody = preg_replace('/(width)=("[^"]*")/i', 'width="495"', $blogbody);
```

The problem I'm running into is the embedded video not working, comes back with an Access Forbidden error (403).  If I remove the line to convert URLS to links, the embedded video works fine.  Not sure how to get these two working together. If anyone else has a better solution to converting URLS to clickable links and resizing embedded video let me know!

Comment: ereg_replace is deprecated http://php.net/manual/en/function.ereg-replace.php

Comment: Your first regex replace is replacing the embed url with a malformed url.

Answer (score 0):

This might be happening because the link which you use to embed the video also gets his `<a href=''>` tags added. So instead of just converting all links, check that they don't have `'` or `"` directly behind or in front of them - this will make sure that the embedded videos' links won't get anchor tags.

Comment: Not too sure how I would go about doing that..any ideas?

Comment: Uhm, will quikly look around. (I have no idea how `"[[:alpha:]]+://[^<>[:space:]]+[[:alnum:]/]"`-type-of-stuff works.)